# For loop "TypeError: string indices must be integers" - nested python dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, nested, indices

I need help with nested python dictionaries:

```
{
    'kind': 'value',
    'code': value,
    'status': 'value',
    'data': {
        'id': 'value',
        'sS': value,
        'mU': value,
        'mD': value,
        'history': [
            {'from': 'value', 'to': 'value', 'sS': value, 'eTf': value},
            {'from': 'value', 'to': 'value', 'sS': value},
            {'from': 'value', 'to': 'value', 'sS': value},
            {'from': 'value', 'to': 'value', 'sS': value},
            {'from': 'value', 'to': 'value', 'sS': value},
            {'from': 'value', 'to': 'value', 'sS': value},
            {'from': 'value', 'to': 'value', 'sS': value},
            {'from': 'value', 'to': 'value', 'sS': value},
            {'from': 'value', 'sS': value}
        ]
    }
}
```

I've played around with nested loops, but all I get is "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Can you help me with the syntax, so I can get the values of - data': {'id': 'value', 'sS': value, 'mU': value, 'mD': value,...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what have you tried? Include what youve tried in the question

Comment: History is a list of dicts. So you need to access that list by integer index. for example `print(content['data']['history'][2]['from'])`

Comment: Thanks Chris Doyle. I can access this data. I can not access this part:
'data': {
        'id': 'value',
        'sS': value,
        'mU': value,
        'mD': value,
...............................

I need syntax for the values of  'id', 'sS', 'mU', 'mD'.

Comment: you can access them with `content['data']['id']`, `content['data']['sS']`